# SQL Query to find deference between sum of two fields in different table

Tags: sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have 3 tables as follows. I want to find balance

```
Table A
studentID       Name
1               Bob
2               Sam
3              Sara

Table B
id  studentID   Credit
1   1       100
2   1       150
3   2       150
4   2       150
5   3       100
6   3       200

Table C
id  studentID   Amount      Type
1   1             50        cash
2   1            120        card
3   2            100        cash
4   2            130        card
5   3            50         card
6   3            150        card
```

I want to get a result table as follows where Balance = Sum(credit) - sum(amount) where type = card.

result Table

```
studentID       Name    Credit  Amount  Balance
1               Bob     250      120    130
2               Sam     300      130    170
3               Sara    300      200    100
```

EDIT
According to his comment this is the query he has tried

```
select A.studentID,
       A.Name,
       ISNULL(SUM(B.Credit),0) as [Credit], 
       ISNULL(SUM(C.Amount),0) as [Amount], 
       ISNULL(SUM(B.Credit),0) - (select ISNULL(SUM(C.Amount),0) from C Group by C.studentID having C.Type='card' and C.studentID=A.studentID) as [balance] 
from A 
  left outer join B on A.studentID = B.studentID 
  left outer join C on B.studentID = C.studentID 
group by A.studentID
```

Comment: I don't understand the math you used to arrive at your expected output.  But beyond this, have you tried something yet?

Comment: What is the role of `type` column?

Comment: this is what i have tried. But its not working
_select A.studentID,A.Name,ISNULL(SUM(B.Credit),0) as [Credit], ISNULL(SUM(C.Amount),0) as [Amount],
ISNULL(SUM(B.Credit),0) - (select ISNULL(SUM(C.Amount),0) from C Group by C.studentID having C.Type='card' and C.studentID=A.studentID) as [balance]
from A left outer join B on A.studentID = B.studentID
left outer join C on B.studentID = C.studentID
group by A.studentID_

Comment: Type is mode of payment. If he paid by cash it should not deduct from Credit

Comment: Please add the query you have tried to your question, not just put it here as a comment.I have done it for you now but please do it like this in the future

Comment: @Vahid Why does Bob's [Amount] = 120 in the result table?

Comment: Sorry. I missed second row in table C. I have edited Table now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handles students with no credit/amounts:

```
SELECT  A.STUDENTID, A.[NAME]
    , sum(B.CREDIT) AS [CREDIT]
    , sum(C.AMOUNT) AS [AMOUNT]
    , sum(B.CREDIT) - sum(C1.AMOUNT) AS [BALANCE]
FROM @TABLEA A
INNER JOIN (SELECT A.STUDENTID, isnull(SUM(B.CREDIT), 0) AS CREDIT FROM @TABLEA A LEFT JOIN @TABLEB B ON A.STUDENTID = B.STUDENTID GROUP BY A.STUDENTID) B ON A.STUDENTID = B.STUDENTID
INNER JOIN (SELECT A.STUDENTID, isnull(SUM(C.AMOUNT), 0) AS AMOUNT FROM @TABLEA A LEFT JOIN @TABLEC C ON A.STUDENTID = C.STUDENTID WHERE [TYPE] = 'CARD' GROUP BY A.STUDENTID) C ON B.STUDENTID = C.STUDENTID
INNER JOIN (SELECT A.STUDENTID, isnull(SUM(C.AMOUNT), 0) AS AMOUNT FROM @TABLEA A LEFT JOIN @TABLEC C ON A.STUDENTID = C.STUDENTID WHERE [TYPE] = 'CARD' GROUP BY A.STUDENTID) C1 ON B.STUDENTID = C1.STUDENTID
group by  A.STUDENTID, A.[NAME]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine

```
SELECT
a.studentid,
a.Name,
sum(b.Credit) AS Credit,
ISNULL(c.Amount,0) AS Amount,
sum(b.Credit) - ISNULL(c.Amount,0) AS Balance
FROM  a
INNER JOIN  b ON a.studentid = b.StudentID
LEFT JOIN (select sum(amount) amount,studentid from c where type='card' 
group by studentid) as c ON a.studentid = c.studentid
GROUP BY a.studentid, a.Name,c.Amount
```

[SQL Fiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/05fb1/1)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it. Please let me know.

```
SELECT A.studentID,A.Name,B.Credit,C.Amount,(Credit-Balance) as Amount from A, B, C where A.studentID=B.studentID=C.studentID AND B.id=C.id AND C.type="card";
```

Comment: This will exclude any StudentIDs without a 'card' entry, which is probably not what he wants.

Comment: He has mentioned that he wants only the results with the type as card

Comment: Could be read both ways I guess.  Also your `WHERE` statement for the joins is not T-SQL compliant.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. It assumes all students in A are in B.  The left join caters for the fact that not all may have a 'card' amount, and returns a 0 if they do not (otherwise a credit subtracted by a `NULL` will return `NULL` balance).

```
   SELECT
    a.StudentID,
    a.Name,
    sum(b.Credit) AS Credit,
    ISNULL(sum(c.Amount),0) AS Amount,
    sum(b.Credit) - ISNULL(sum(c.Amount),0) AS Balance
    FROM tableA as a
    INNER JOIN tableB as b ON a.StudentID = b.StudentID
    LEFT JOIN tableC as c ON a.StudientID = c.StudentID AND c.[Type] = 'card'
    GROUP BY a.StudentID, a.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be my start point. To be sure about the right calcs.
Then I'll start to refactor.

```
 SELECT a.*, 
   (SELECT SUM(b.credit) FROM TableB b WHERE a.studentID = b.studentID) as Credit,
   (SELECT SUM(c.amount) FROM TableC c WHERE a.studentID = c.studentID) as Amount,
   ((SELECT SUM(b.credit) FROM TableB b WHERE a.studentID = b.studentID)
    - 
   (SELECT SUM(c.amount) FROM TableC c WHERE a.studentID = c.studentID)) as Balance
  FROM TableA a;
```

I made a sqlFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b86dc/7

Answer (score 0):

You can try a query like below

<kbd>**[See live demo](http://rextester.com/IAJXB33303)**</kbd>

```
select A.*, credit, amount, balance= coalesce(credit,0) - coalesce(amount,0) from
[table A] A
left join
(
select 
    studentid,
    credit= sum(credit)
from [table b] b 
group by studentid
)B
    on A.studentID= B.studentID
left join
(
select 
    studentid,
    amount= sum(amount)
from [table C] 
group by studentid
)C
on A.studentID=C.studentID
```